# Windows Azure Cloud Connection String

Tags: windows, azure, connection-string

I am having a trouble in between azure local and azure cloud connection string. so, can anyone suggest me how to setup cloud connection string in .csdef and local.cscfg and cloud.cscfg. file. How to setup Connection string to run queue, blob, table run in cloud???

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve. What have you tried ? What queues, blob and table are all different systems.

Comment: Maybe you are looking at how to set up the Storage connection string differently locally and then have it something else when you deploy? If so check out this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh369934.aspx